# how to have multiple background with different height one below the other

Tags: html, css, animation, background, css-animations

Hi how can I have more than one background here in CSS that I can set one bellow the other, without seeing the same one in loop ?

I tried so many things from the background position but nothing works for me

I can see only the same first URL in loop ?

Can someone explain me how to have 9 different backgrounds in this example ?

```css
.overlay{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  
  background: url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6eaeec90e00222e7f62_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6fb04d71200247e15fb_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6feec730a0022b756d4_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6ed7e627d0022f7acad_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6f020ea4d00234326ee_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6f7271d190023cb958e_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b702271d190023cb95b6_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6f4eab9f000229958a9_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6e6fe83f10024675e66_optimized_990);

  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-size: 100%!important;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 2796px, 0px 5592px, 0px 8388px, 0px 11184px, 0px 13980px,  0px 16776px, 0px 19572px, 0px 22368px, 0px 25164px;
  -webkit-animation:100s scroll infinite linear;
  -moz-animation:100s scroll infinite linear;
  -o-animation:100s scroll infinite linear;
  -ms-animation:100s scroll infinite linear;
  animation:100s scroll infinite linear;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width:648px;
  height:450px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}




@-webkit-keyframes scroll{
  100%{
    background-position:0px -25164px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll{
  100%{
    background-position:0px -25164px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes scroll{
  100%{
    background-position:0px -25164px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes scroll{
  100%{
    background-position:0px -25164px;
  }
}

@keyframes scroll{
  100%{
    background-position:0px -25164px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: why my question earned a -1  without explanations ? what's wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Some tips on how `background` works

1. `background` is  a shortcut property so it will override all the previously defined `background-XX` properties.  So move your `background-repeat` and `background-size` below the `background:..` in the rule.
2. Since the `background:..` also sets the `background-position` for all images to be the same, they are stacked on top of each other. You will need to provide a `background-position: .. ;` with multiple values to position all images one after the other.
3. When you set a single `background-X:..` property with a single value, it will apply to all background images. So in your animation you will have to define a new position for each image, using multiple values.
4. I am not sure you can achieve an animation like this and keep it responsive in the container, due to how `background-position` interprets percentage values. But if you do not need responsiveness then the above tips should get you there.

---

Update: Adding a JS implementatio of calculating the `background-position` for the images and for the keyframes.

```js
function attachBackgroundHandler() {
  const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
  const keyframeCssContainer = document.querySelector('#dynamicCss');
  const heightRatio = 1312 / 990; // image original height / image original width
  const backgroundImageCount = 9;

  function calculateBackgroundPositions() {
    const overlayWidth = overlay.clientWidth;
    const height = overlayWidth * heightRatio;
    const totalAnimationHeight = height * (backgroundImageCount - 1);
    const backgroundPositionValues = [];
    const backgroundAnimationPositions = [];

    for (let p = 0; p < backgroundImageCount; p++) {
      const position = height * p;
      backgroundPositionValues.push(`0px ${position}px`);
      backgroundAnimationPositions.push(`0px ${-totalAnimationHeight + position}px`);
    }

    overlay.style.backgroundPosition = backgroundPositionValues.join();
    keyframeCssContainer.textContent = `
@keyframes scroll {
  100% {
    background-position: ${backgroundAnimationPositions.join()};
  }
}
  `
  };

  calculateBackgroundPositions();

  window.addEventListener('resize', calculateBackgroundPositions);
}

attachBackgroundHandler();
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6eaeec90e00222e7f62_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6fb04d71200247e15fb_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6feec730a0022b756d4_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6ed7e627d0022f7acad_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6f020ea4d00234326ee_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6f7271d190023cb958e_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b702271d190023cb95b6_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6f4eab9f000229958a9_optimized_990), url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5eaf48a4da467d0022126577/6166b6e6fe83f10024675e66_optimized_990);
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 2796px, 0px 5592px, 0px 8388px, 0px 11184px, 0px 13980px, 0px 16776px, 0px 19572px, 0px 22368px, 0px 25164px;
  animation: 100s scroll infinite alternate linear;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 648px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -1312px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<style id="dynamicCss"></style>
```

Comment: wow you build your answer like it's needed, I've updated my code and I totally understand what you mean now.  You're right, if I want to make this kind of animation in responsive. How can I do that even if I want to use js ? I can set a different value but if I use different px for each background it will not work in responsive mode, same if I replace px by percentage. Do you think I achieve it or I can only use 3 different background where I will add top, center and bottom position ? Jut to help, actually I have 9 background have same width and height

Comment: Jut to help, actually I have 9 background width and heigh, 2110px x 2796px. so I understand you and add different background position where I can add 2796px for each background. but as I said, px will not work in responsive mode, and percentage won't be really precise !! that's why I ask if we can create something with js where we can use the height of each background ?

Comment: @fatyfatoumata added a JS implementation for the calculations. Note that i am using an extra `<style>` tag to update the keyframes as well.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but can't achieve it, take a look here to the result : https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/vzyfag9h/8/

I just updated the size of the image in your js part, I don't know why, but the slider move faster after some seconds ?

Comment: I wanted something like that but vertically

Comment: @fatyfatoumata so ,in my example i had decreased the duration of the animation from 100s to 10s to test it. And i also added the `alternate` keyword in the animation. If you remove those it should be as the original animation. Also the images you use as background are 1312x990 so not sure why you use 2796x2110

Comment: @fatyfatoumata also what browser are you using?

Comment: Hi I'm using safari but have chrome, firefox and opera... and you're right about the size, 2110x2796 are on my desktop !! le